# ElasticSearch: Exact value from array of values

Tags: elasticsearch

## set mapping

```
"set": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "doc_values": true,
                        "fields": {
                           "criteria": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "norms": {
                                 "enabled": false
                              },
                              "analyzer": "analyzer_exact"
                           },
                           "fulltext": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "norms": {
                                 "enabled": false
                              },
                              "analyzer": "insight_analyzer_fulltext"
                           }
                        }
                     }
```

## Set Values:

```
"set": [
                     "Cleaning",
                     "Physical Abilities"
                  ],
```

When querying this,

```
{
  "fields": ["set"], 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "FIELD",
      "query": "(set.criteria: \"cleaning\")"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

> Cleaning
>
> Physical Abilities

This is the existing system, my task is to split the exact result and the co-occurring result. Which means for the above query the result must be "cleaning" only.

Is there any way I can get it by doing a change in query or data mapping?

Comment: have you tried using bool query rather wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understood very well, but if you want to return only results that match with exact value, you should use "query term":

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: As set contains a list of values, it always returning the all the co- occuring values. Term Query not working in my case.